# macOS Catalina cannot be installed on Macintosh HD

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, upgrade, catalina

I have MacBook Air (Early 2015) yet the installer says "macOS Catalina cannot be installed on Macintosh HD" when I try to upgrade from macOS Mojave (10.14.6). I have 8.7GB of disk space available.

What does that mean? any options?

Comment: It means that it can't be installed.  You do not have enough free disk space for the installer to make the necessary adjustments.  You have a problem anyway, macOS is not performant with that little free space in any case.

Comment: @MarcWilson hi! in case you might want to add something to this question of mine: [What are the risks with low disk space on a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371483/what-are-the-risks-with-low-disk-space-on-a-mac)